# Disable loading Visual Assist X when launching Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist

Is there any way to disable VA X when launching VS and turn it back on only when needed? Since it will cause some lag. I seem can't find the option either in VS's option or VA's option.

Answer (score 4):

Hold the `shift` key down when Visual Studio starts up - this will prevent all addins from loading (at least in more recent versions of Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2):

In VS2013,

1. On the **Tools menu**, click **Extensions and Updates**.
2. In the **Extensions and Updates** dialog box, locate Visual Assist.
3. **Disable** it.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Assist has a command to disable its features; Enable/Disable is located on the Visual Assist menu.   You could run that command (for example via a macro) at startup, then re-enable when you wanted to you use its features.  However, you can't do this at the same time as preventing it from loading.